# Xdebug is installed, but not showing up on phpinfo

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to install xdebug on my ubuntu linux system.

Correct .so file, make install everything is correct, just maybe the php.ini configuration?

I use the installation wizard.

[Installation Wizard Step by Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGzA6.png)

I am at step 9, added the zend_extension on my INI file.
Added Zend Extension Command on other INI file.

when i PHP_INFO(), xdebug just does not appear in the list.

I googled around and seems other people php.ini file have this

```
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp
```

but mine does not?

So i added those into my php7.4/cli/php.ini
still does not show on my phpinfo?

I go to the terminal and type php info xdebug seems there. xdebug support => enabled Version => 2.9.6

but i created a testpage.php and put phpinfo();

xdebug does not appear in the page?

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to update your php.ini file. Below is the code lines that i added in my php.ini file.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "path of you extension example /usr/lib/php/xdebub.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
```

Must restart your server after any changes in php.ini file.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment. 

I added 

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
```

just after OPCACHE on my PHP.INI file. then created a testrun.php with php info inside but there's no xdebug :(

Comment: you restarted server?

Comment: Yes, apache2 restarted, php7.4fpm restarted, php7.4 restarted

Comment: I go to the terminal and type php info
xdebug seems there.

xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.9.6
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business: https://xdebug.org/support

Debugger => enabled
IDE Key => bft-server-2

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On